# How to create nuget custom command in Package manager console?

Tags: powershell, nuget-package

I have some nuget packages and its Installation/Uninstallation works fine in Dialog mode and package manager console mode.

I need to Implement the package installation in some conditions in console mode.

Normally i used that command to installation

```
PM>Install-Package mypackageMVC3.40
PM>Install-Package mypackageMVC3.45
```

Now i need to install some assemblies from mypackage

I would expect package manager console to look similar to the following

```
PM> Install-Package mypackage.Group1.Mvc
Successfully installed 'group11.dll'.
Successfully installed 'group12.dll'.
Successfully added 'group11.dll' to MvcApplication.
Successfully added 'group12.dll' to MvcApplication.**
```

I need to Installation and Uninstallation like this command.